# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class DataLayer.HibernateAdapter

Tags: java, hibernate-annotations, hibernate-session

I have modified my Java project(Web service) into Dynamic web module. I'm using Tomcat 7.0.59 as server. While starting server it is getting started without any issues. But once if I tried to access the Web service method then I will end up with the error saying that -"*Could not initialize class DataLayer.HibernateAdapter java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class DataLayer.HibernateAdapter*". Anyone please help me than just marking it a "Duplicate". If code has to be modified, please provide me detail steps. Thanks!!

**Console Log:**

```
Mar 10, 2015 2:09:07 PM com.sun.xml.ws.server.sei.EndpointMethodHandler invoke
SEVERE: Could not initialize class DataLayer.HibernateAdapter
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class DataLayer.HibernateAdapter
    at DataLayer.DatabaseContext.<init>(DatabaseContext.java:12)
    at DataLayer.ConsumerDetails.getConsumerdetails(ConsumerDetail.java:84)
    at ManageLayer.Authenticate(AuthenticationManager.java:50)
    at ManageLayer.Console.GetProductsList(Console.java:484)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.server.InstanceResolver$1.invoke(InstanceResolver.java:246)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.server.InvokerTube$2.invoke(InvokerTube.java:146)
```

**DatabaseContext.java :**

```
public class DatabaseContext
{
    private final Session session;

    public DatabaseContext() {
        this.session = HibernateAdapter.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    }

    public Session delegate() {
        return session;
    }

    public void close() {
        session.flush();
        session.close();
    }
}

class HibernateAdapter
   {
    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();

    private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
        try 
        {

            return new AnnotationConfiguration()
            .addAnnotatedClass(Consumer.class)
            .addAnnotatedClass(Product.class)
            .addAnnotatedClass(PriceTag.class)
            .addAnnotatedClass(Barcode.class)
            .configure().buildSessionFactory();
        } 
        catch (Throwable e) 
        {
            System.err.println("Exception while creating Initial SessionFactory" + e);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(e);
        }
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() 
    {
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    public static void shutdown() {
        getSessionFactory().close();
    }
}
```

Comment: did you checked whether `DataLayer.HibernateAdapter` is in the jar which you are referring ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `NoClassDefFoundError` usually indicates that your class path is not correct. Check if you have the right Hibernate libraries in your class path. e.g. in the project settings, if you are using Eclipse. Right now, you are not including the `DataLayer.HibernateAdapter` class correctly, so Tomcat cannot find it.